# ANSI terminal - rewrite the output

Tags: terminal, tmux

**i'm working on a new tool which rewrites multiple lines on the terminal BUT not using ncurses.** so far it seemed to work great - until i discovered the problem i'm asking about here!

i don't find a way to remove the last 30 rows, if my terminal can only display 20 rows at a time, so the not seen last 10 rows can't be modified. as a result it will produce 10 more output lines on every redraw of my statusbar. if i then use the scrollback of konsole it looks like a mess.

## the problem in detail

when i run ./demo2 on a terminal (konsole, xterm like) and everything fits into the viewable area (i got a pretty big screen and resolution on my xserver) everything works as expected, see the screenshots from below.

however, if i shrink konsole, parts of the dynamically rewritten area (it starts with --------------------) are not deleted anymore since the terminal seems unable to reach it for some unknown reason.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_terminal says:

> ```
> CSI n A   CUU – Cursor Up Moves the cursor n (default 1) cells
> CSI n B   CUD – Cursor Down
> CSI n C   CUF – Cursor Forward
> CSI n D   CUB – Cursor Back
> ```
>
> If the cursor is already at the edge of the screen, this has no effect.

this is exactly what i noticed, **it can't be done using these functions**. do you have an idea what i could do to fix that?

i tried various other terminal escape sequences and none worked. all i want to do is to rewrite the buffer of what is currently displayed on the terminal.

**please note: i know ncurses but i would like to have this functionality without using it.**

## ideally: the DOM terminal

it would be cool to edit the terminal output like it was a DOM tree. so that i could update single elements like a status-widget. i could then have IDs for single elements and update only these, without touching other elements before or after - ideally not loosing the user's selection (made with the mouse). maybe TMUX is what i want but after looking at that i didn't see how to make it work.

that would pretty much reimplement X-widget style rendering on a terminal!

ideas welcome! ;-)

## see my project [demo2.cpp] at:

- https://github.com/qknight/nix-build-hack

see the screenshots:

- https://raw.github.com/qknight/nix-build-hack/master/screenshot1.jpeg
- https://raw.github.com/qknight/nix-build-hack/master/screenshot2.jpeg

Comment: http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html

Comment: Now you know why people use ncurses!

Comment: it seems what i wanted is not possible so i will use ncurses. anyway i think that what i wanted to do is a very interesting use case. too bad this can't be done.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S-Lang_(programming_library)#Screen_Management

Comment: zsh seems to be doing nearly what i want. when you do: ls -la <tab> you get a autocompletion list which is not drawn in fullscreen. however, if you scroll the view and the output changes (for example when hitting 'left' or 'right' key, it will reset the view to the end). maybe this happens for every terminal-write, not just for interactive user inputs.